# Avoid infinite loop with 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm using `.htaccess` to redirect

```
http://www.example.com/foo/
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/foo/bar
```

This is my code:

```
redirect 301 /foo/ http://www.example.com/foo/bar
```

However this produces a feedback loop, something like

`http://www.example.com/foo/barbarbarbarbarbar` etc.

I've tried placing delimiters around it:

```
redirect 301 ^/foo/$ http://www.example.com/foo/bar
```

but then the redirect simply doesn't take place. I'm probably missing some very simple point of syntax. Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's my (almost) full `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Canonical is www version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#redirect => http unless special page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(javascripts|images|library|stylesheets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#redirect => https for special pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# send to router
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you have more rules in this .htaccess? If yes then show full .htaccess here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Canonical is www version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#redirect => http unless special page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(javascripts|images|library|stylesheets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#redirect => https for special pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^foo/?$ /foo/bar [L,NC,R=301]

# send to router
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**make sure to test this in a new browser or clear your browser cache before testing.**

Answer (score 1):

For your information, it really depends on your hosting provider. It may be behind a Load Balancer and you don't have the proper env var set (like HTTPS and others...).

In my case ([Infomaniak](https://www.infomaniak.com)), nothing actually worked and I got infinite redirect loop.

The right way to do this for Infomaniak is [actually explained in their support site](https://www.infomaniak.com/en/support/faq/1961/redirecting-all-visitors-to-the-site-using-https-ssl):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://your-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, always check with your hosting provider. Hopefully they have an article explaining how to do this. Otherwise, just ask the support.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is the resource that you want to expose with your redirect.
Is it a file or a directory.

if you would expose a directory under bar you should try :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/foo/ http://www.example.com/foo/bar/
```

if you would redirect to a file you should use this syntax :

```
redirect 301 /foo http://www.example.com/foo/bar
```

you can see this [post](http://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/301-redirects/) for more informations

Comment: As I said, the first one produces a feedback loop. As it happens, so does the second one.

Comment: Take attention on the slash characters.

Comment: It still produces a feedback loop.

Comment: sorry I've edit my post to use the correct syntax for directory redirect. It was an error in my first answer.

Comment: This fails to redirect (as in my question, where I used `^` in an attempt to delimit the `foo` part of the URI).

Comment: it also append with RedirectMatch ?

Comment: Sorry, missed that. No, with RedirectMatch it causes another redirect loop.

Comment: Is http://www.example.com/foo/bar point to a folder or on a file ? you should not redirect a folder path to a file path

Comment: Neither -- they are purely symbolic names which are handled by a router.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using redirect, you can use passthrough.

```
RewriteRule ^/foo$ /foo/bar [PT]
```